# Make php-fpm log as root:adm

Tags: logging, php-fpm

I want to make sure members of the `adm` groups can read all logs, and the php-fpm process makes an exception as it logs `php5-fpm.log` under `root:root` and `u=r+w`

I can't find a way to achieve this. I've considered using `syslog.facility` directives but I'd rather keep a dedicated log file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should read more carefully the manual on [PHP FPM Configuration](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php) `php-fpm.conf` directives:

- The `syslog.facility` directive only controls the *facility* type and is by *default* set to `daemon`. This doesn't affect the *location*. Non-normative *syslog facilities* are defined in [RFC 5424, 6.2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424#section-6.2.1). As you can see, facilities 16-23 are for local use and you could dedicate one for PHP FPM.
- The correct directive for sending log to syslogd instead of local file is `error_log syslog`, while the *default* value is `#INSTALL_PREFIX#/log/php-fpm.log`.
- Another important directive here is `syslog.ident php-fpm` (that is the *default* value).

On configuration level there's nothing about file permissions. You'd have to get on the source code level to figure out how it's actually done. Some advice changing log file permissions on an init script.

### One Logrotate to rule them all

File permissions can be controlled in [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) configuration, which also has `create` directive.

```
/var/log/php-fpm.log {
    create 0640 root adm
}
```

---

### Syslogd & dedicated facility

Using the [Syslogd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/syslogd) enables configuring all file locations on the same [`syslog.conf`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/syslog.conf). It is still possible to configure syslogd to use separate log file for PHP FPM by the dedicated facility, e.g. `local4`:

```
# /etc/syslog.conf

local4.*    /var/log/php-fpm.log
```

---

### Rsyslog filters

If you're using [rsyslogd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/rsyslogd), you can [*filter*](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/filters.html) the PHP-FPM's `syslog.ident` *prepended* to every message:

```
# /etc/rsyslog.conf

:syslogtag, isequal, "php-fpm"    /var/log/php-fpm.log
:syslogtag, isequal, "php-fpm"    ~
```

With rsyslogd, file permissions are also set in the `rsyslog.conf`:

```
# Set the default permissions for all log files.
#
$FileOwner root
$FileGroup adm
$FileCreateMode 0640
$DirCreateMode 0755
$Umask 0022
```

Comment: Thanks, the `logrotate` configuration is what I was looking for. But interesting point on how to properly use syslog!